# Add column after merge with original data set name

Tags: r, merge

Say I have these two data frames on which I want to perform a full merge, how can I get a fourth column indicating the original data frame the information comes from, i.e. for a row that is observed only in `df1`, write `df1`, for a row that is observed only in `df2`, write `df2`, and for a row observed in both, write `both`.

```r
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:10, cat = rpois(10, 1))
df2 <- data.frame(id = 8:13, dog = rpois(6, 1))

merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE, ...)

#    id cat dog which
# 1   1   0  NA   df1
# 2   2   1  NA   df1
# 3   3   1  NA   df1
# 4   4   2  NA   df1
# 5   5   0  NA   df1
# 6   6   2  NA   df1
# 7   7   3  NA   df1
# 8   8   1   0  both
# 9   9   1   0  both
# 10 10   0   1  both
# 11 11  NA   1   df2
# 12 12  NA   2   df2
# 13 13  NA   1   df2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a small function that does the job.

```
check_from <- \(X, j, df1, df2) {
  j <- deparse(substitute(j))
  y <- X[, j]
  y <- replace(y, y %in% df1[, j] & y %in% df2[, j], 'both')
  y <- replace(y, y %in% df1[, j], 'df1')
  y <- replace(y, y %in% df2[, j], 'df2')
  cbind(X, from=y)
}

merge(df1, df2, all=TRUE) |> check_from(id, df1, df2)
#    id cat dog from
# 1   1   0  NA  df1
# 2   2   1  NA  df1
# 3   3   1  NA  df1
# 4   4   2  NA  df1
# 5   5   0  NA  df1
# 6   6   2  NA  df1
# 7   7   3  NA  df1
# 8   8   1   0 both
# 9   9   1   0 both
# 10 10   0   1 both
# 11 11  NA   1  df2
# 12 12  NA   2  df2
# 13 13  NA   1  df2
```

Can be expanded to cases when `by.x` and `by.y` are different.

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:10, cat = rpois(10, 1))
df2 <- data.frame(id = 8:13, dog = rpois(6, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use more common packages and construct it yourself:

```
merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(which = case_when(id %in% setdiff(df1$id, df2$id) ~ 'df1',
                           id %in% setdiff(df2$id, df1$id) ~ 'df2',
                           T ~ 'both'))

# id cat dog which
# 1   1   1  NA   df1
# 2   2   0  NA   df1
# 3   3   1  NA   df1
# 4   4   1  NA   df1
# 5   5   1  NA   df1
# 6   6   0  NA   df1
# 7   7   3  NA   df1
# 8   8   2   1  both
# 9   9   3   0  both
# 10 10   1   0  both
# 11 11  NA   2   df2
# 12 12  NA   1   df2
# 13 13  NA   1   df2
```

Comment: That's a good idea, although it might break easily once the merge is more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collapse::join`'s `column` argument which does exactly that:

```r
library(collapse)
join(df1, df2, how = "full", column = "which")

#    id cat dog   which
# 1   1   0  NA     df1
# 2   2   1  NA     df1
# 3   3   1  NA     df1
# 4   4   2  NA     df1
# 5   5   0  NA     df1
# 6   6   2  NA     df1
# 7   7   3  NA     df1
# 8   8   1   0 matched
# 9   9   1   0 matched
# 10 10   0   1 matched
# 11 11  NA   1     df2
# 12 12  NA   2     df2
# 13 13  NA   1     df2
```